# displaying custom container on different screens

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get my container to look exactly the same on all devices.I get that the Media Query class helps but i'm still lost.I'm still trying to retain the dimension of my container which is 200*200. I don't intent to change to another  widget because I've used the container in various sections of my app, everything doesn't size up well except the app bar.This is my code.

```
 Widget _buildCard(String title) => Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            height: 115,
            width: 115,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

This is the app on my test device.
[image]

This is the app on another device .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understanding what your problem is, you're looking for something similar to `dp` in Android.

This can be achieved by doing some calculations.

First of all, you're going to need the value of `devicePixelRatio` which is a property of [MediaQueryData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html).

Once you access that, you can do something like this:

1. Get a reference device (e.g. your phone) and its `devicePixelRatio` value, which we'll call `p1`.
2. Set a size for the container, let's say 200.
3. When assigning the value, calculate a proportion between the current device pixel ratio and the reference.

Assuming `h` is the reference height (200 in our example) and `pr2` the `devicePixelRatio` of the current device, the calculation is solving the following proportion:

```
h : pr1 = x : pr2
```

Which solves in:

```
x = h * pr2/pr1
```

Using `x` as the dimension will bring equal size on each screen, just like `dp` in Android. This because we're making a proportion between the different densities of pixels that different screens have.

A simpler way might be forcing the `devicePixelRatio` by wrapping your app in a [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) and specifying the new value. This way you could always use the same value, since you're forcing `pr2` to be equal to `pr1`.

This is an idea and I have not tested it (while I've used the first approach in the past).